Imagick command line to wrap image on another image like cover image
How to make cover image using source and map image.
Source image wrap on map image on gray shape and generate like result image
using imagick command line
Source image:

map image:

Result image:

convert source2.png -resize "$(identify -format '%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]!' map_1.png)" map_1.png -alpha on -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
wrong image generate: 
Above command line image is cutting instead of shape like resulting image.
